# Правильное фонетическое название буквы "Ф"

Tags: грамматика

Правильное фонетическое название этой буквы - "ЭФ" или "ФЭ". Насколько я помню, в старой советской школе эта буква звучала как "ФЭ". Ошибаюсь ли я?

Answer (score 5):

"ФЭ" эта буква не называлась никогда. Древнейшее "ферт" сменилось современным "эф".
Произношение "ФЭ" или "Ф" закрепилось только при прочтении некоторых аббревиатур - ФРГ [фэ-эр-гэ], ФГОУ [фгоу].

Answer (score 1):

**Ф** (алфавит и названия букв):
***эф***
Орфографический словарь, проф. Д.Н.Ушаков, **1938**
Орфографический словарь, проф. Д.Н.Ушаков и доц. С.Е.Крючков, **1952**
Орфографический словарь русского языка под ред. С.И.Ожегова и А.Б.Шапиро, **1957**

[В Википедии есть такая статья:
**Ф, ф** (название: современное *эф*, ранее *фэ* (в советской школе), в аббревиатурах иногда *фэ*) — буква всех славянских кириллических алфавитов...
[**Википедия, Ф**](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A4)]

**Откуда** взялась такая информация? — неизвестно.
В 1918 году везде стали писать *ферт*, который был переименован на современный лад в ***эф***, что подтверждают **данные  советских словарей**.

(В пример можно привести аббревиатуру:
***РСФСР

[эр-эс-эф-эс-эр]***
Российская Советская Федеративная Социалистическая Республика.

Малый академический словарь. — М.: Институт русского языка Академии наук СССР. Евгеньева А. П. 1957—1984.)

Про особенности появления, написания и использования **Ф** можно посмотреть здесь:
[**Буква Ф в русском языке**](http://www.textologia.ru/russkiy/alfavit-istoria/istoria-bukv/bukva-f/313/?q=463&n=313)
[**Фокус с раздвоением**](http://www.vokrugsveta.ru/vs/article/8126/)

Comment: *ранее фэ (в советской школе)* - был какой-то момент, когда детям вдалбливали нечто наподобие *"Буква эф обозначает звук фе"*. Может, оттуда.

Answer (score 0):

Насколько я помню из школы, сейчас правильно эта буква называется "ЭФ".

Answer (score 0):

Называется ЭФ, но раньше называлась ферт, достаточно редкая буква, с неё начинались заимствованные слова: ферзь, флагман.